# Expected number of variables that are at least n

Tags: probability

I wasn't sure what to title this.

**We have n objects distributed uniformly and independently at random among n people. Calculate the expected number of people that receive at least 5 objects.**

I know how to calculate the probability that one person receives at least 5 objects, but I do not know to calculate the expected number, as it seems that the probability of the second person receiving 5 objects depends on the first, and so on. Is this just using an indicator variable for each person or is there more involved?

Comment: Yes, indicator random variables, standard calculation.  "Dependence" makes no difference.

Comment: Indeed the number of persons that receive at least $5$ objects is $$X_1+\cdots+X_n$$ where $X_i=1$ if the person $i$ receives at least $5$ objects and $X_i=0$ otherwise, hence the mean number of persons that receive at least $5$ objects is $$E(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n).$$ Since, by symmetry, $E(X_i)$ does not depend on $i$, the result is $nE(X_1)$, that is, $n$ times the probability that some given person receives at least $5$ objects. Crucially, expectation is linear hence, when applied to a sum, it forgets the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Expected value is linear.
If $p$ is the probability that any particular person (does something), and there are $n$ people, then the expected number of people who (do something) is $n p$.